# How can I get the total in a many to many relationship?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, group-by, count

I am using wxpython and sqlite3 to build a simple song organizer.

There are the following tables

- songs
- files
- tags
- playlists

Songs and files have an One To One relationship.

Songs and tags have a Many To Many relationship.

Songs and playlists have a Many To Many relationship.

Below you can see the table queries I am using:

```
create_songs_table_query = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs (
                                song_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                title text NOT NULL,
                                artist text NOT NULL,
                                added_timestamp integer NOT NULL,
                                file_id INTEGER NULL,
                                    FOREIGN KEY (file_id)
                                    REFERENCES files (file_id)
                                    ON DELETE CASCADE
                    ); """

create_files_table_query = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (
                                        file_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                        filename text NULL,
                                        size integer NULL,
                                        song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                            FOREIGN KEY (song_id)
                                            REFERENCES songs (song_id)
                                            ON DELETE CASCADE                                
                                ); """

create_tags_table_query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (
                                 tag_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                 tag_text  text NOT NULL,
                                 tag_timestamp integer NULL,

                                ); """

create_songs_tags_table_query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs_tags (
                                    song_tag_id  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                    song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                            FOREIGN KEY (song_id)
                                            REFERENCES songs (song_id)
                                            ON DELETE CASCADE,  
                                    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                            FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
                                            REFERENCES tags (tag_id)
                                            ON DELETE CASCADE  
                                    ); """

create_playlists_table_query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (
                                      playlist_id  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                      playlist_title text NOT NULL,
                                      created_timestamp  INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                      updated_timestamp  INTEGER NULL,
                                    ); """

create_songs_playlists__table_query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs_playlists (
                                            song_playlist_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                            song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                                    FOREIGN KEY (song_id)
                                                    REFERENCES songs (song_id)
                                                    ON DELETE CASCADE,
                                            playlist_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                                        FOREIGN KEY (playlist_id)
                                                        REFERENCES playlists (playlist_id)
                                                        ON DELETE CASCADE  
                                        ); """
```

I am trying to get how many songs each playlist has in total,including if any playlist has 0 songs.

I use the following query which seems to return the desired results:

```
SELECT playlists.playlist_id, playlists.playlist_title, COUNT(songs.song_id) as total
FROM playlists 
LEFT OUTER JOIN songs_playlists 
ON playlists.playlist_id = songs_playlists.playlist_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN songs
ON songs_playlists.song_id = songs.song_id
GROUP BY (songs.song_id)
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Although, I am not sure if it is totally correct or maybe there is a more simple or efficient way to do  it.

Comment: The query I use here doesn't work, I was mistaken.

Comment: Your query should work. The problem is that some of your CREATE statements are syntactically incorrect

Comment: @forpas Could you elaborate on the correct syntax ?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get how many songs each playlist has in total,including if any playlist has 0 songs.

You can indeed start from `playlists` table, then bring the `songs_playlists` with a `left join`, then aggregate. However, you don't need the `songs` table to get the result that you desire, and, more important, you need to `group by` playlist, not by song:

```
select p.playlist_id, p.playlist_title, count(sp.playlist_id) no_songs
from playlists p
left join songs_playlists sp on sp.playlist_id = p.playlist_id
group by p.playlist_id, p.playlist_title
```

A correlated subquery might also be an acceptable approach, since it avoids the need for outer aggregation:

```
select
    p.*,
    (select count(*) from songs_playlists sp where sp.playlist_id = p.playlist_id) no_songs
from playlists p
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite requires that if you use the `FOREIGN KEY (columnname)....` syntax to define foreign keys to place all these definitions after the definitions of the columns (at the end of the `CREATE` statement).
Also you have commas in 2 of the `CREATE` statements right before the closing parenthesis which must be removed.
These are the incorrect statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (
   tag_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   tag_text  text NOT NULL,
   tag_timestamp integer NULL, -- remove the last comma
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs_tags (
  song_tag_id  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (song_id) REFERENCES songs (song_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, -- move to the end 
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tags (tag_id) ON DELETE CASCADE  
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (
  playlist_id  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  playlist_title text NOT NULL,
  created_timestamp  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  updated_timestamp  INTEGER NULL, -- remove the last comma
); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs_playlists (
  song_playlist_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (song_id) REFERENCES songs (song_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, -- move to the end 
  playlist_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (playlist_id) REFERENCES playlists (playlist_id) ON DELETE CASCADE  
);
```

All the statements corrected:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs (
  song_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  title text NOT NULL,
  artist text NOT NULL,
  added_timestamp integer NOT NULL,
  file_id INTEGER NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES files (file_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (
  file_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  filename text NULL,
  size integer NULL,
  song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (song_id) REFERENCES songs (song_id)  ON DELETE CASCADE
); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (
  tag_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  tag_text  text NOT NULL,
  tag_timestamp integer NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs_tags (
  song_tag_id  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,  
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (song_id) REFERENCES songs (song_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tags (tag_id) ON DELETE CASCADE  
); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (
  playlist_id  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  playlist_title text NOT NULL,
  created_timestamp  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  updated_timestamp  INTEGER NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs_playlists (
  song_playlist_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  playlist_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (song_id) REFERENCES songs (song_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (playlist_id)  REFERENCES playlists (playlist_id) ON DELETE CASCADE  
);
```

Your query should work although you don't need the last join to `songs`.